# JsonConvert.SerializeObject is changing a property value from a letter (char) to a number (int)

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

JsonConvert.SerializeObject is changing a property value from letters to a number. I say 'letters' and 'number' as its a dynamic source object, both before and after are strings but the value 'D' in the source dynamic object is coming out as '1' after serializing to JSON.

**SourceObject**

```
public class Response
{
    public dynamic DataBlocks { get; set; }
}
```

Response.DataBlocks.*dynamic.dynamic*.PropertyInQuestion == "D"

**Serialization Code**

```
var serializedResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
```

Results in serializedResponse.*dynamic.dynamic*.PropertyInQuestion == "1"

The result is different depending on which character is in the source property, and its always consistent;

- C -> 0
- D -> 1
- G -> 5
- M -> 4
- PC -> 2
- PD -> 3
- PM -> 6

This is the data being sent through SerializeObject:

```
 public enum PropertyInQuestionType {
    C,
    D,
    PC,
    PD,
    M,
    G,
    PM,
    PG,
    U,
    KP,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you are getting is most likely setting the `PropertyInQuestion` to an `Enum`

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` serializes `Enum` as `int`.
And because the property is dynamic when deserializing you get back an int.

You can, however, use `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter` and it will serialize it as string.

This also mean that when deserializing you will get a string (not an enum).

```
var serializedResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, new StringEnumConverter());
```